# Can't understand how the authors got this equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Let us consider a two-qubit system (A and R) initially entangled as given by:
$$
\left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  = \alpha \left| {{0_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{1_R}} \right\rangle  + \beta \left| {{1_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_R}} \right\rangle 
$$
where ${\left| \alpha  \right|^2} + {\left| \beta  \right|^2} = 1$. By using the fact that Rob’s detector is the only one which interacts with the field, the initial state of the total system is:
$$\left| {\Psi _{ - \infty }^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle  = \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle $$
where $\left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle $ the Minkowski vacuum.  The final state of the qubit-field system can be described as:
$$\left| {\Psi _\infty ^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle  = \left( {I + a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )R - {a_{RI}}(\bar \lambda ){R^\dagger}} \right)\left| {\Psi _{ - \infty }^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle $$
where $I$ is the identity matrix with the same dimension of $\left| {\Psi _{ - \infty }^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle $. ${D^\dagger}\left| 1 \right\rangle  = D\left| 0 \right\rangle  = 0$, $D\left| 1 \right\rangle  = \left| 0 \right\rangle $, and ${D^\dagger}\left| 0 \right\rangle  = \left| 1 \right\rangle $, ($D \in A,R$) are the raising and lowering operators for the qubit.

Using the first two equations in the last one, the authors got:
$$\left| {\Psi _\infty ^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle  = \left| {\Psi _{ - \infty }^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle  + \alpha \left| {{0_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_R}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left( {a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )\left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle } \right)\\
+ \beta \left| {{1_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{1_R}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left( {{a_{RI}}(\bar \lambda )\left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle } \right)$$
Please, could someone explain to me how the authors got this equation?

The intended equation is Eq. (3.6) in 10.1103/PhysRevA.80.032315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$
\left| {\Psi _\infty ^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle  
= \left( {I + a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )R - {a_{RI}}(\bar \lambda ){R^\dagger}} \right)\left| {\Psi _{ - \infty }^{AB\phi }} \right\rangle
= \left( {I + a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )R - {a_{RI}}(\bar \lambda ){R^\dagger}} \right)
\left( \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle \right)
\\
= \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle
+ a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )R \left( \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle \right)
- {a_{RI}}(\bar \lambda ){R^\dagger}\left( \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle \right)
$$
Then, for the second term,
$
a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )R \left( \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle \right)
= R\left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle \otimes a_{RI}^\dagger(\lambda )\left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle,
$
where
$$
R\left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle 
= R \left( \alpha \left| {{0_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{1_R}} \right\rangle  + \beta \left| {{1_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_R}} \right\rangle \right)
= \alpha \left| {{0_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes R\left| {{1_R}} \right\rangle  + \beta \left| {{1_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes R \left| {{0_R}} \right\rangle
\\
= \alpha \left| {{0_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_R}} \right\rangle  + \beta \left| {{1_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes R 0
= \alpha \left| {{0_A}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_R}} \right\rangle
.
$$
Likewise for the third term, $- {a_{RI}}(\bar \lambda ){R^\dagger}\left( \left| {{\Psi _{AR}}} \right\rangle  \otimes \left| {{0_M}} \right\rangle \right)$.